# Java - Can't write object as file to directory

Tags: java, file, object, io, directory

I have a weird problem with my program.
I wrote a small program to write an object to a file in a specific directory.

Player-Class:

```
package readwrite;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int level;

    public Player(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Level: " + level;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

}
```

PlayerReaderWriter-Class:

```
package readwrite;

import java.io.*;

public class PlayerReaderWriter {

    public static Player readPlayer(String path) {
        Player p = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            p = (Player) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p;
    }

    public static void writePlayer(String path, Player p) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                file.createNewFile();
            } else {
                file.mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(p);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player p = new Player("Foo", 64);
        p.printInfo();
        writePlayer("players/Player.ser", p);

        Player q = readPlayer("players/Player.ser");
        q.printInfo();
    }

}
```

The problem is: When I run my program for the first time, when the **directory** "players" doesn't exist, I get the following error:

```
D:\Projects>java readwrite/PlayerReaderWriter
Name: Foo, Level: 64
java.io.FileNotFoundException: players\Player.ser (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at readwrite.PlayerReaderWriter.writePlayer(PlayerReaderWriter.java:34)
        at readwrite.PlayerReaderWriter.main(PlayerReaderWriter.java:47)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: players\Player.ser (Access is deniedt)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at readwrite.PlayerReaderWriter.readPlayer(PlayerReaderWriter.java:11)
        at readwrite.PlayerReaderWriter.main(PlayerReaderWriter.java:49)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at readwrite.PlayerReaderWriter.main(PlayerReaderWriter.java:50)
```

Now the directory "players" has been created by the program and for some reason it also created a **subdirectory** named "Player.ser".

When I run it a second time, it works and creates a "Player.ser" **file** within the "players" directory.

When I run it with just a empty directory named "players" it also won't work.

Regards :)

Comment: I believe you get what you’re asking for. :-) First time, the file does not exist, so your program does file.mkdirs() — this create directory players and *directory* Player.ser. Next time the directory Player.ser exists (you didn’t ask if it was a directory, only if it existed), so your program deletes the directory and creates a file instead. With just an empty players directory you get the first behaviour except the players directory isn’t created since it is already there, the rest is the same. BTW you ought to have been able to reproduce the behaviour in a much smaller example. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
    file.createNewFile();
} else {
    file.mkdirs();
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

You're saying that if `players/Player.ser` doesn't exist, you should create it *as a directory* - and then also as a file. That's broken.

You don't need to delete the file at all if it already exists - you can just use a `FileOutputStream` and let it overwrite the file, truncating it to start with, as is the default behaviour.

You just need to check whether the *directory* exists first, e.g.

```
File file = new File(path);
File parent = file.getParentFile();
// TODO: Handle parent existing, but not being a directory,
// or file existing, but being a directory...
if (!parent.exists()) {
    parent.mkdirs();
}

try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note the try-with-resources statement so that your output stream is *always* closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: `getParentFile()` instead of `getParent()` :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the JavaDoc on `File#mkdirs()`:

> Creates the directory named by *this* abstract pathname ...

That says that the file is assumed to represent a directory, hence `Player.ser` is created as a directory. Use `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` instead (keep in mind that depending on the path there might be no parent).

Since your code is creating a directory any write operation to that `File` object will fail since you can't write data directly into a directory.